# 'SearchUsers' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I have problem with this it keeps saying: 'SearchUsers' object has no attribute 'count'

#views

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q

class SearchUsers(PaginatedElasticSearchAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    document_class = UserDocument

    def generate_q_expression(self, query):
        return Q('bool',
                 should=[
                     Q('match', username=query),
                     Q('match', first_name=query),
                     Q('match', last_name=query),
                 ], minimum_should_match=1)
```

#urls

```
from django.urls import path
from search.views import SearchUsers

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:query>/', SearchUsers.as_view()),
]
```

I'm facing this issue for the last 3 days. Searched for the similar question on StackOverflow but nothing helped me.
Any Help, Would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'
```

I forget to add in my settings, which I passed through the class parameter. It solved my issue.